# Power operator calculating wrong results

Tags: php

In real sense both of these are the same but they both return different results.

```
echo round(200 / ((175/100)*(175/100)), 2);   Returns 65.31
echo round(200 / ((175/100)^2), 2);           Returns 66.67
```

The order of operations is all correct so that should have no effect in the results.
[Created a codepad](http://codepad.org/Oxi4uQpV)

Comment: When all else fails, [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

^ means bitwise XOR, not power. For power use the function pow:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php